# How to create Gradle BootRun Tasks with CLI-Args input

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

#### Context:

I am trying to create two tasks which activate a `BootRun` Task in gradle. I call these tasks from other modules) It is a SpringBootApp which accepts command-line arguments and takes the action based on the argument given as input. Apart from that it's code generator/ table generator,if that helps.

#### Gradle

```
task generateClass(dependsOn:":tools:codegen:clean") {
    bootRun {
        args = ["--class"]
    }

}

task generateMetadata(dependsOn:":tools:codegen:clean") {
        bootRun {
            args = []
            args = ["--metadata"]
        }


}



generateClass.finalizedBy generateClass:bootRun
generateMetadata.finalizedBy generateMetadata:bootRun
```

#### Problem

The Problem with the above it is that whenever I call the **BootRun** from either `GenerateClass` or `GenerateMetadata` task, it calls a single `BootRun` without the arguments I have set for the task.

```
Should Work:
GenerateClass --> ClassArgs --> Run
GenerateMetadata --> MetadataArgs --> Run

But Works as: 
Args = which ever task from above runs first, their arguments are set.
So sometimes it is 
GenerateClass --> MetadataArgs --> Run
GenerateMetadata --> MetadataArgs --> Run
or
GenerateClass --> ClassArgs --> Run
GenerateMetadata --> ClassArgs --> Run
```

So my solution is either creating a custom bootRun Task with different arguments or passing CLI arguments effectively by running the task.

**NOTE**: Yes the SpringBoot CLI parsing is correct as I have tested it. Plus I call these tasks from other modules.

Comment: Tasks don't call or configure other tasks in Gradle. They just depend on other tasks. If you want to have two tasks that start your application, then configure the standard bootRun task to have one, and create another task, also of typeBootRun, but with a different coniguration.

Comment: How do I add Type to a task exactly!? I added type: bootRun but it didn't evaluate! Any link to a tut would be helpful! Thank You!

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:defining_tasks. The example defines a task of type `Copy`. You want a task of type `org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:defining_tasks) linked by [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) ! I created these BootRun task which take commandLineArguments and also use spring-profiles! Hope this is useful :)

```
task generateClass(type: org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun, dependsOn: 'build') {
        doFirst() {
            main = 'com.etcbase.uyap.generator.GeneratorApplication'
            classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
            args '--class'
            systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', 'dev'
        }
    }

    task generateMetadata(type: org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun, dependsOn: 'build') {
        doFirst() {
            main = 'com.etcbase.uyap.generator.GeneratorApplication'
            args '--metadata'
            classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
            systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', 'test'
        }
    }
```